# Is there a standard for job sectors?

Tags: money

Is there any sort of recognised standard (e.g. ISO) for grouping jobs into job sectors e.g. 'technology', 'emergency services'?

I asked this on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37545741/is-there-an-iso-standard-for-job-sectors) and they suggested this SE.

Would [this](https://www.prospects.ac.uk/jobs-and-work-experience/job-sectors) be as close as I'm likely to get?

Comment: The [NACE codes](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/ramon/nomenclatures/index.cfm?TargetUrl=LST_NOM_DTL&StrNom=NACE_REV2&StrLanguageCode=EN&IntPcKey=&StrLayoutCode=HIERARCHIC&CFID=1110191&CFTOKEN=3ca0f6dadb71d377-1F2DE4F0-F7BF-BCAE-31C18C386EA88F92&jsessionid=f900daad75c14b465532m) are along the lines of what you're looking for, but I'm not sure they'd be useful for your application.

Comment: Government agencies in North America use NAICS and SIC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NAICS seems to be what you're getting at (http://www.census.gov/eos/www/naics/). This is the industry classification mechanism in North America. If you are interested in groups of workers' tasks as opposed to groups of establishments, you might be interested in occupation, which is the Standard Occupation Classification (SOC) system (http://www.bls.gov/soc/).